# dash, plotly, python, webpage, data

Tags: python, css, pandas, database, dataframe

I wrote callbacks for apply and clear buttons for material selection tool. I select `material` from dropdown and click apply, it will insert that value to the Material column of the table according to the active cell. If I click clear it will clear that row of Material column according to the active cell.  It is giving error

In the callback for output(s):
datatable-upload.data
Output 0 (datatable-upload.data) is already in use.
To resolve this, set `allow_duplicate=True` on
duplicate outputs, or combine the outputs into
one callback function, distinguishing the trigger
by using `dash.callback_context` if necessary.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output,State
import dash_table
import pandas as pd
import io
import base64

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

#Create a default DataFrame with the desired columns and a single row
default_data = [{'Name': '', 'Size': '', 'Material': '', 'Fixed': '', 'Tree Info': ''}]
default_columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in default_data[0].keys()]

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Upload(
            id='upload-data',
            children=html.Div([
                html.P('Select a file.', style={'margin': 0}),
            ]),
            style={
                'width': '75%',
                'height': '45px',
                'lineHeight': '40px',
                'borderStyle': 'solid',
                'borderWidth': '1px',
                'borderRadius': '1px',
                'borderColor': 'gray',
                'textAlign': 'center',
                'margin': '10px',
                'cursor': 'pointer',
                'background-color': '#f0f0f0',
            },
            multiple=False
        ),
        html.Button('Cancel', id='cancel-button', disabled=True,
                    style={'width': '75%',
                           'cursor': 'pointer',
                           'border': 'none',
                           'margin-left': '10px',
                           'border-radius': '1px',
                           'background-color': '#f0f0f0',
                           'color': 'gray'}),
        
        html.Div([
            html.Button('Tick Selected Rows', id='button-1',
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '30px',
                               'lineHeight': '30px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}),
            html.Button('Untick Selected Rows', id='button-2',
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '5px',
                               'lineHeight': '30px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'})
        ], style={'float': 'down', 'width': '100%'}),
        
        html.Div([
            html.P("Material Selection Tool", className="simple-text", style={'margin-left': '20px'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='material-selection',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'AL5052', 'value': 'AL5052'},
                    {'label': "Pc", 'value': 'Pc'},
                    {'label': "Glass", 'value': 'Glass'},
                    {'label': "Tape", 'value': 'Tape'}
                ],
                placeholder='Select a material.',
                style={'width': '90%'}
            ),
            html.Button('Apply', id='apply-button',n_clicks=0,
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '2px',
                               'lineHeight': '20px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}),
            html.Button('Clear', id='clear-button', n_clicks=0,
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '2px',
                               'lineHeight': '20px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}
                       )
        ], style={'float': 'down', 'width': '100%'}),
        
        html.Div([
            html.P("Fixed Condition Selection Tool", className="simple-text", style={'margin-left': '20px'}),
            html.Button('Apply', id='apply-button-fix',n_clicks=0,
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '2px',
                               'lineHeight': '20px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}),
            html.Button('Clear', id='clear-button-fix', n_clicks=0,
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '2px',
                               'lineHeight': '20px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}
                       )
        ], style={'float': 'down', 'width': '100%'}),
        
    ], style={'float': 'left', 'width': '40%'}),
    
    html.Div([
            dash_table.DataTable(id='datatable-upload', style_table={'height': '600px'},
                             data=default_data,
                             page_current=0,
                             columns=default_columns,
                             style_header={'fontWeight': 'bold', 'textAlign': 'center'},
                             editable=True,
                             filter_action="native",
                             sort_action="native",
                             sort_mode="single",
                             column_selectable="multi",
                             row_selectable="multi",
                             row_deletable=False,
                             selected_columns=[],
                             selected_rows=[],
                             page_action="native",
                             style_cell={
                                 'minWidth': 95, 'maxWidth': 95, 'width': 95
                             },
                             style_cell_conditional=[
                                 {
                                     'if': {'column_id': c},
                                     'textAlign': 'left'
                                 } for c in ['country', 'iso_alpha3']
                             ],
                             style_data={
                                 'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                                 'height': 'auto'
                             }
                             ),
    ], style={'float': 'left', 'width': '100%'}),
], style={'width': '100%', 'overflow': 'auto', 'display': 'flex'})
```

this is my layout.

```
#callback for tick and untick buttons
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-upload', 'selected_rows'),
    Input('button-1', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('button-2', 'n_clicks'),
    State('datatable-upload', 'active_cell'),
    State('datatable-upload', 'selected_rows'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_selected_rows(button_1_clicks, button_2_clicks, active_cell, selected_rows):
    ctx = dash.callback_context

    if not ctx.triggered:
        return selected_rows

    trigger_id = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]

    if trigger_id == 'button-1':
        if active_cell and active_cell['row'] not in selected_rows:
            selected_rows.append(active_cell['row'])
        return selected_rows
    elif trigger_id == 'button-2':
        if active_cell and active_cell['row'] in selected_rows:
            selected_rows.remove(active_cell['row'])
        return selected_rows
    else:
        return selected_rows
    

#callback for drag and cancel buttons. 
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-upload', 'data'),
    Output('datatable-upload', 'columns'),
    Output('cancel-button', 'disabled'),
    Output('cancel-button', 'style'),
    Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
    Input('cancel-button', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_output(contents, n_clicks):
    if contents is None:
        return default_data, default_columns, True, {'color': 'gray'}

    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        return default_data, default_columns, True, {'color': 'gray', **default_cancel_button_style}

    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
    
    data = df.to_dict('records')
    columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in df.columns]

    # Check if data has been uploaded and change the color of the cancel button
    if len(data) > 1:
        cancel_button_style = {'color': 'black', **default_cancel_button_style}
    else:
        cancel_button_style = {'color': 'gray', **default_cancel_button_style}
    
    return data, columns, False, cancel_button_style

# Callback for applying material and clearing rows
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-upload', 'data'),
    Input('apply-button', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('clear-button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('material-selection', 'value'),
    State('datatable-upload', 'active_cell'),
    State('datatable-upload', 'data'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def apply_material_and_clear_rows(apply_clicks, clear_clicks, selected_material, active_cell, data):
    # Make a copy of the data to avoid modifying the original data directly
    updated_data = data.copy()

    if apply_clicks and active_cell:
        row = active_cell['row']
        updated_data[row]['Material'] = selected_material

    if clear_clicks:
        for row in updated_data:
            if row['id'] in active_cell['row_ids']:
                row['Material'] = ''

    return updated_data





if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=4000)
```

This is my callbacks.

I tried dcc.Store to use the same component in 2 callbacks, but I could not use correctly or not, it did not work. Please help me with using it for my code.

```
# Callback for applying material and clearing rows
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-upload', 'data'),
    Input('apply-button', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('clear-button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('material-selection', 'value'),
    State('datatable-upload', 'active_cell'),
    State('datatable-upload', 'data'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def apply_material_and_clear_rows(apply_clicks, clear_clicks, selected_material, active_cell, data):
    # Make a copy of the data to avoid modifying the original data directly
    updated_data = data.copy()

    if apply_clicks and active_cell:
        row = active_cell['row']
        updated_data[row]['Material'] = selected_material

    if clear_clicks:
        for row in updated_data:
            if row['id'] in active_cell['row_ids']:
                row['Material'] = ''

    return updated_data
```

Here `Output('datatable-upload', 'data')` is giving an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few problems:

- when you have multiple callbacks that target the same output, you need to pass the argument `allow_duplicate=True` to prevent Dash from throwing an error (it's best to combine multiple callbacks that target the same output into one callback to avoid a race condition, but I will leave it as is)
- as far as I can tell, the condition `if row['id'] in active_cell['row_ids']:` will lead to `KeyError` because `id` isn't a valid key in row, and `row_ids` isn't a valid key in active_cell

I created a csv with some sample data:

```
Name,Size,Material,Fixed,Tree Info
0,a,1,AL5052,False,
1,b,2,Pc,False,
2,c,3,Glass,False,
3,d,4,Tape,False,
4,e,5,Tape,False,
```

I rewrote a few parts of your Dash app, and the apply and clear buttons should now be working.

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, ctx, State, dash_table
import pandas as pd
import io
import base64

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

#Create a default DataFrame with the desired columns and a single row
default_data = [{'Name': '', 'Size': '', 'Material': '', 'Fixed': '', 'Tree Info': ''}]
default_columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in default_data[0].keys()]

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Upload(
            id='upload-data',
            children=html.Div([
                html.P('Select a file.', style={'margin': 0}),
            ]),
            style={
                'width': '75%',
                'height': '45px',
                'lineHeight': '40px',
                'borderStyle': 'solid',
                'borderWidth': '1px',
                'borderRadius': '1px',
                'borderColor': 'gray',
                'textAlign': 'center',
                'margin': '10px',
                'cursor': 'pointer',
                'background-color': '#f0f0f0',
            },
            multiple=False
        ),
        html.Button('Cancel', id='cancel-button', disabled=True,
                    style={'width': '75%',
                           'cursor': 'pointer',
                           'border': 'none',
                           'margin-left': '10px',
                           'border-radius': '1px',
                           'background-color': '#f0f0f0',
                           'color': 'gray'}),
        
        html.Div([
            html.Button('Tick Selected Rows', id='button-1',
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '30px',
                               'lineHeight': '30px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}),
            html.Button('Untick Selected Rows', id='button-2',
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '5px',
                               'lineHeight': '30px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'})
        ], style={'float': 'down', 'width': '100%'}),
        
        html.Div([
            html.P("Material Selection Tool", className="simple-text", style={'margin-left': '20px'}),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='material-selection',
                options=[
                    {'label': 'AL5052', 'value': 'AL5052'},
                    {'label': "Pc", 'value': 'Pc'},
                    {'label': "Glass", 'value': 'Glass'},
                    {'label': "Tape", 'value': 'Tape'}
                ],
                placeholder='Select a material.',
                style={'width': '90%'}
            ),
            html.Button('Apply', id='apply-button',n_clicks=0,
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '2px',
                               'lineHeight': '20px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}),
            html.Button('Clear', id='clear-button', n_clicks=0,
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '2px',
                               'lineHeight': '20px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}
                       )
        ], style={'float': 'down', 'width': '100%'}),
        
        html.Div([
            html.P("Fixed Condition Selection Tool", className="simple-text", style={'margin-left': '20px'}),
            html.Button('Apply', id='apply-button-fix',n_clicks=0,
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '2px',
                               'lineHeight': '20px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}),
            html.Button('Clear', id='clear-button-fix', n_clicks=0,
                        style={'width': '75%',
                               'margin-top': '2px',
                               'lineHeight': '20px',
                               'borderStyle': 'solid',
                               'borderWidth': '1px',
                               'borderRadius': '1px',
                               'borderColor': 'gray',
                               'textAlign': 'center',
                               'margin': '10px',
                               'cursor': 'pointer',
                               'background-color': '#f0f0f0'}
                       )
        ], style={'float': 'down', 'width': '100%'}),
        
    ], style={'float': 'left', 'width': '40%'}),
    
    html.Div([
            dash_table.DataTable(id='datatable-upload', style_table={'height': '600px'},
                             data=default_data,
                             page_current=0,
                             columns=default_columns,
                             style_header={'fontWeight': 'bold', 'textAlign': 'center'},
                             editable=True,
                             filter_action="native",
                             sort_action="native",
                             sort_mode="single",
                             column_selectable="multi",
                             row_selectable="multi",
                             row_deletable=False,
                             selected_columns=[],
                             selected_rows=[],
                             page_action="native",
                             style_cell={
                                 'minWidth': 95, 'maxWidth': 95, 'width': 95
                             },
                             style_cell_conditional=[
                                 {
                                     'if': {'column_id': c},
                                     'textAlign': 'left'
                                 } for c in ['country', 'iso_alpha3']
                             ],
                             style_data={
                                 'whiteSpace': 'normal',
                                 'height': 'auto'
                             }
                             ),
    ], style={'float': 'left', 'width': '100%'}),
], style={'width': '100%', 'overflow': 'auto', 'display': 'flex'})


#callback for tick and untick buttons
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-upload', 'selected_rows'),
    Input('button-1', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('button-2', 'n_clicks'),
    State('datatable-upload', 'active_cell'),
    State('datatable-upload', 'selected_rows'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_selected_rows(button_1_clicks, button_2_clicks, active_cell, selected_rows):
    if not ctx.triggered:
        return selected_rows

    trigger_id = ctx.triggered[0]['prop_id'].split('.')[0]

    if trigger_id == 'button-1':
        if active_cell and active_cell['row'] not in selected_rows:
            selected_rows.append(active_cell['row'])
        return selected_rows
    elif trigger_id == 'button-2':
        if active_cell and active_cell['row'] in selected_rows:
            selected_rows.remove(active_cell['row'])
        return selected_rows
    else:
        return selected_rows
    

#callback for drag and cancel buttons. 
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-upload', 'data', allow_duplicate=True),
    Output('datatable-upload', 'columns'),
    Output('cancel-button', 'disabled'),
    Output('cancel-button', 'style'),
    Input('upload-data', 'contents'),
    Input('cancel-button', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def update_output(contents, n_clicks):
    default_cancel_button_style = {'color': 'black'}
    if contents is None:
        return default_data, default_columns, True, {'color': 'gray'}

    if n_clicks is not None and n_clicks > 0:
        return default_data, default_columns, True, {'color': 'gray', **default_cancel_button_style}

    content_type, content_string = contents.split(',')
    decoded = base64.b64decode(content_string)
    df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(decoded.decode('utf-8')))
    
    data = df.to_dict('records')
    columns = [{'name': col, 'id': col} for col in df.columns]

    # Check if data has been uploaded and change the color of the cancel button
    if len(data) > 1:
        cancel_button_style = {'color': 'black', **default_cancel_button_style}
    else:
        cancel_button_style = {'color': 'gray', **default_cancel_button_style}
    
    return data, columns, False, cancel_button_style

# Callback for applying material and clearing rows
@app.callback(
    Output('datatable-upload', 'data', allow_duplicate=True),
    Input('apply-button', 'n_clicks'),
    Input('clear-button', 'n_clicks'),
    State('material-selection', 'value'),
    State('datatable-upload', 'active_cell'),
    State('datatable-upload', 'data'),
    prevent_initial_call=True,
)
def apply_material_and_clear_rows(apply_clicks, clear_clicks, selected_material, active_cell, data):
    # Make a copy of the data to avoid modifying the original data directly
    updated_data = data.copy()

    if ("apply-button" == ctx.triggered_id) and active_cell and (selected_material != None):
        row = active_cell['row']
        updated_data[row]['Material'] = selected_material

    if ("clear-button" == ctx.triggered_id) and active_cell:
        row = active_cell['row']
        del updated_data[row]

    return updated_data


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=4000)
```

[image]

Comment: It worked, you have no idea about how much you helped me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you're welcome – glad to have helped!